# How implement a Master Detail in a Web Form using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i'm starting to work with Entity Framework and i would like to know how to implement a master detail web form that permit the user to insert the details in a datagrid before saving it to the database using entity framework 4.

Thanks in advance.
Jean Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these tutorials, hope it helps:
[Using the GridView and the EntityDataSource](http://aspalliance.com/1951_ASPNET_40_and_the_Entity_Framework_4__Part_5__Using_the_GridView_and_the_EntityDataSource.all)
[Master/Detail Using a Selectable Master GridView with a Details DetailView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx)

Comment: No images in the first link. :-/